# Virus-safe first boot without CDROM

Tags: installation, malware, secure-boot

My previous PC has very strange symptoms and I've become very paranoid about malware. I've purchased all-new hardware to ensure I have a known-clean PC. I've spent a good bit of cash, and want peace of mind as I install my OS. (Probably Windows, which is the only OS I really use, although this will just be the virtualization host.)

I own Windows, but not a Windows CD or a CD drive (although I would begrudgingly purchase both to solve this). **Is there a secure method I can use to ease my paranoia about planting malware on my new PC as I bootstrap it?**

For example, maybe I can create a boot utility flash disk and then inspect the image checksum from another platform (such as Android) to make the likelihood of a matching attack vanishingly small.

Or maybe there's a simpler way? Please recommend.

Comment: I think this question is to open ended. But if you want to exercise your paranoia muscle then use a burned disk instead of a flash drive. Some flashdrives firmware allow for persistent malware even if you reformat them. A single session CD would be a lot harder to change. Download the iso on a compromised computer if you'd like and burn it but then on an isolated computer like a library computer calculate the ISOs sha1 sum.

Comment: Or [List of USB Flash Drives with Hardware Write Protection Switch « Fencepost Software & Consulting](https://www.fencepost.net/2010/03/usb-flash-drives-with-hardware-write-protection/)